# Can an Android Library Project (APKLIB) be obfuscated by Proguard?

Tags: android, maven, obfuscation, proguard, android-library

I am attempting to obfuscate an Android Library Project (APKLIB), allowing the library to distributed to potential clients for test development without compromising the majority of the source code.

Unfortunately, there is no documentation and no examples that Google can provide, and the only references to obfuscated APKLIBs are question posts with no solutions.

I have attempted to use the android-maven-plugin as well as the maven-proguard-plugin with Maven to obfuscate the APKLIB, but the end result is not obfuscated. I also tried moving the proguard goal to the process-classes and prepare-package phases of maven with no success.

My last resort is splitting the source code out of the APKLIB and obfuscating it as a JAR, while leaving the APKLIB as AIDL files and resources with a dependency on the obfuscated JAR. However, I would like to avoid this if possible since our project has a large number of libraries already.

Does anyone know if it is even possible to obfuscate an APKLIB? And if so, how?

Comment: How do you like your clients use your apklib?

Comment: The APKLIB is part of a development kit and contains a series of AIDL files and parcelable classes, allowing a third-party developer to interface with our remote service over IPC.

Answer (score -1):

Hi are you asking about creating a obfuscated jar file?

You can do that by adding build.xml file to it and making changes in your proguard-project.txt file and running "`ant release`" from command line and you will find the obfuscated.jar under a proguard folder in your bin folder of project.

Steps;

-> To add build.xml in your project in linux  open a terminal and go to android/tools/ant folder and run `./android update project -p /path of your android library project`. And you will find build.xml in your project root directory.

-> To enable Obfuscation in your project in your editor open a `project.properties` file and remove comment from `proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

-> Add your changes to proguard-project.txt file and in terminal go to your project and run ant release

Comment: if you insist on spreading multiple copies of the ever same answer, please at least do it with a _formatted_ version: there's no code, so no need for using the code tag on normal text. Be sure to read the formatting help (click the question mark when editing ...)